# Controlling the keyboard from a html page

Tags: android, windows, keyboard, mouse

First of all let me explain my situation:

I am developing a 8 player game for a company, which is going to be placed in a Shopping mall, for customer's entertainment.

The Platform is  a round table, where people can stand in a circle to play the game.

The problem is , we want to let the users to connect their own Android Devices to the Game Computer via USB or WiFi or Bluetooth , and use their Android Devices like a controller. But not exactly like a controller , We just need 2-3 keystrokes from them, for instance lets say we need (W-A-S) from them to control the game character.

But there is some apps already in the Android Store which makes the Android device as a Keyboard and Mouse to control the computer.

But not every person would like to install an app in their devices right? So is there any other way?

Thanks in Advance.

Game Development Using Unity3D

Comment: What kind of technology is used for developing the game?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell tat , I am using Unity 3D with  C# script

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can build html page with that keys and send these commands to the server via ajax whenever users click some of them (this is easy task). Also you can provide every visit to the page with different hash or id or something and send this value with every command sent to the server, so you can know where the commands come from...

Comment: I can create a html and I can get the inputs as you said, but how to convert it as a keystroke that my computer can understand tat it is coming from its own keyboard?

Comment: Because you are using C#, I am suggesting you to write an ASP.NET page. When some visitor visit the page for the first time - you are transferring him a (for example) a hash result from function as time parameter when he visit the page (in ms). This will create a unique identifier for every user, and you are going to store these values in database. Next, when you have those values transferred to the client, like I said, you are going to send these values with every AJAX call you make when the user press some of the key. I don't know the background of the game but this should work...

Comment: And when I am saying keyboard, I doesn't mean the real Android/iPhone keyboard, instead of that I am thinking of the keyboard build in the webpage, for example a normal buttons.

Comment: I got tat somehow , I will let you know what the result is, asap